# Installing RabbitMQ on Minikube

Tags: kubernetes, rabbitmq, minikube

I'm currently building a backend, that among other things, involves sending RabbitMQ messages from localhost into a K8s cluster where containers can run and pickup specific messages.

So far I've been using Minikube to carry out all of my Docker and K8s development but have ran into a problem when trying to install RabbitMQ.

I've been following the RabbitMQ Cluster Operator official documentation ([installing](https://www.rabbitmq.com/kubernetes/operator/install-operator.html)) ([using](https://www.rabbitmq.com/kubernetes/operator/using-operator.html)). I got to the "Create a RabbitMQ Instance" section and ran into this error:

```
1 pod has unbound immediate persistentVolumeClaims
```

I fixed it by continuing with the tutorial and adding a PV and PVC into my RabbitMQCluster YAML file. Tried to apply it again and came across my next issue:

```
1 insufficient cpu
```

I've tried messing around with resource limits and requests in the YAML file but no success yet. After Googling and doing some general research I noticed that my specific problems and setup (Minikube and RabbitMQ) doesn't seem to be very popular. My question is, have I passed the scope or use case of Minikube by trying to install external services like RabbitMQ? If so what should be my next step?

If not, are there any useful tutorials out there for installing RabbitMQ in Minikube?

If it helps, here's my current YAML file for the RabbitMQCluster:

```
apiVersion: rabbitmq.com/v1beta1
kind: RabbitmqCluster
metadata:
  name: rabbitmq-cluster
spec:
  persistence:
    storageClassName: standard
    storage: 5Gi
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: rabbimq-pvc
spec:
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 5Gi
  volumeMode: Filesystem
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: rabbitmq-pv
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 5Gi
  volumeMode: Filesystem
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Recycle
  storageClassName: standard
  hostPath:
    path: /mnt/app/rabbitmq
    type: DirectoryOrCreate
```

Edit:

Command used to start Minikube:

```
minikube start
```

Output:

```
  minikube v1.17.1 on Ubuntu 20.04
✨  Using the docker driver based on existing profile
  Starting control plane node minikube in cluster minikube
  Restarting existing docker container for "minikube" ...
  minikube 1.18.1 is available! Download it: https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/releases/tag/v1.18.1
  To disable this notice, run: 'minikube config set WantUpdateNotification false'

  Preparing Kubernetes v1.20.2 on Docker 20.10.2 ...
  Verifying Kubernetes components...
  Enabled addons: storage-provisioner, default-storageclass, dashboard
  Done! kubectl is now configured to use "minikube" cluster and "default" namespace by default
```

Comment: Hi ! Can you provide the command you used to start minikube to see the options and driver, pls ?

Comment: @MarcABOUCHACRA Post has been edited with command and output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the command you used to start minikube, the error is because you don't have enough resources assigned to your cluster.
According to the source code from the rabbitmq cluster operator, it seems that it needs 2CPUs.

You need to adjust the number of CPUs (and probably the memory also) when you initialize your cluster. Below is an example to start a kubernetes cluster with 4 cpus and 8G of RAM :

```sh
minikube start --cpus=4 --memory 8192
```

If you want to check your current allocated ressources, you can run `kubectl describe node`.

Comment: This seemed to work, now got a working pod and no errors in the dashboard which is the furthest I've got so far. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Raising cpus and memory definitely gets things un-stuck, but if you are running minikube on a dev machine - which is probably a laptop - this is a pretty big resource requirement. I get that Rabbit runs in some really big scenarios, but can't it be configured to work in *small* scenarios?

Comment: Do you mean this as a solution to the problem described at the top of the page? It reads more like a comment with/or a follow up question.